# Timeout for Swift functions

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, timeout

I finished writing a Swift library, and I need to test its performance on some examples.

I am creating a script in Swift to take some data into files, execute them using my library, and then return results such as execution time.

Among the list of these different examples extracted from these files, some of them could take hours to execute, whereas others could only take some seconds. I do not expect to have an answer for all examples, and I just want the results of those that finish in less than 'x' seconds. For this reason, I want to introduce a timeout if a call of my function takes more than 'x' seconds. It should stop the current execution and go to the next one.

I looked for solutions, some of them using async/await or dispatchQueue, but nothing that worked for me. Below is one of the solutions that I tried:

```swift
func evalWithTimer(key: String, somethingToExecute: SomethingToExecute) -> SVS? {

  var res: SVS? = nil
  // Create a semaphore
  let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

  // Define the time limit in seconds
  let timeLimit: DispatchTime = .now() + 1 // 1 seconds

  // Define the task you want to run (replace this with your actual task)
  let task = {
    res = somethingToExecute.eval()
    semaphore.signal() // Signal that the task is done
  }

  // Execute the task asynchronously
  DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: task)

  // Wait for the task to complete or time out
  let result = semaphore.wait(timeout: timeLimit)

  if result == .timedOut {
    // Task did not complete within the time limit, you can cancel it if needed
    print("Task evaluation timed out and was canceled")
    return res
  } else {
    // Task completed within the time limit
    print("Task evaluation completed within the time limit")
    return res
  }

}
```

My function evalWithTimer is called for different values inside somethingToExecute. When I call `eval()` on it, it can take more than 1 second, and it should be stopped if this is true. In this current version, it does not work because the task `eval()` is not canceled correctly. At least this is my hypothesis. Even adding `task.cancel()` when the timeout is true does not change anything.

The only solutions I found add an asynchronous mechanism, which can be understandable. I am looking for a solution to this problem, based or not on the code above.

Note that `somethingToExecute.eval()` is not asynchronous.

Comment: Stopping things should be a cooperative effort. Can you change how `eval` is implemented?

Comment: Yes, I can, but it implies changing the initial library. What should I do?
Edit: The `eval()` function has a significant impact on the library and has many tests for it. In my case, this is just for testing on my own, but it would not change anything for a user.

Comment: Actually if you are doing this in a testing environment, how about waiting for `XCTestExpectation`? Those methods allow you to specify a timeout. See e.g. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctwaiter/4109475-fulfillment

Comment: When I used the word 'test' in my initial post, I didn't mean the typical testing of a library. The library has already been tested with Swift's testing framework, and everything is okay. Now, I am conducting some benchmarks. This new code is a Swift executable, and I am no longer using Swift's testing framework.

Maybe I should rethink about how I want to collect my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using XCTest if you are doing "tests". You can wait for `XCTestExpectation`s with a timeout.

```
func testExample() {
    let expect = expectation(description: "Eval completed in 1 second")
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        somethingToExecute.eval()
        expect.fulfill()
    }
    wait(for: [expect], timeout: 1)
}
```

When the timeout is exceeded, the test process gets killed.

---

In general though, stopping things should be a cooperative effort. `eval` should check whether itself is cancelled, and if it is, stop whatever it is doing.

For example, using Swift Concurrency, `eval` can check [`Task.isCancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/iscancelled-swift.type.property) at appropriate points in its execution, or if it `throws`, you can `try Task.checkCancellation()` instead.

Suppose `eval` is a long-running loop, you can put the check in each iteration:

```
while something {
    if Task.isCancelled { return nil /* or however you'd like to stop it*/ }
    // or in a throwing function:
    // try Task.checkCancellation()

    // do work
}
```

Then, you can make two tasks, one runs `eval`, another measures 1 second and then cancels the first one.

```
func evalWithTimer(key: String, somethingToExecute: SomethingToExecute) async throws -> SVS? {
    let evalTask = Task {
        somethingToExecute.eval()
        // if eval is throwing,
        // try somethingToExecute.eval()
    }
        
    let timeoutTask = Task {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
        evalTask.cancel()
        // here you know the timeout is exceeded
    }
        
    // if eval is throwing, "try" await, a CancellationError would be thrown if the timeout exceeds
    let result = await evalTask.value
    timeoutTask.cancel()
    return result
}
```